# SQL to select rows only if all of them meet a criteria

Tags: java, sql

I am quite new to SQL and while I can get around writing most of the queries, I am not getting anywhere with this one. I want to achieve this in a single query that I can execute using JPA.

```
TABLE RULE:
RULE_ID   ENABLED
-----------------
1         0
2         0
3         0
4         1
5         1

TABLE MISC:
MISC_ID
--------
1
2

TABLE HOLD:
HOLD_ID   MISC_ID   RULE_ID   READY
------------------------------------
1         1         1         1       
2         1         2         1       
3         1         3         1       
4         2         4         0      
5         2         1         1
```

I want to select from HOLD only the MISC_IDs where each row has READY=1 and RULE_ID is in (RULE_IDs where ENABLED=0). In the above example, the query should return MISC_ID = {1} since HOLD_IDs 1, 2 and 3 all have READY=1 and RULEs 1, 2 and 3 are all disabled.

MISC_ID 2 should not be returned since HOLD_ID 4 has READY=0.

The tables MISC and HOLD have millions of rows but RULE is fairly small (<1000 rows).

Any suggestions on how I could write a native SQL to achieve this? PL/SQL is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MISC_ID
FROM HOLD

GROUP BY MISC_ID
HAVING MIN(READY) <> 0;
```

---

Example run:

```
$ with HOLD (HOLD_ID, MISC_ID, RULE_ID, READY)
as (values
    (1,1,1,1),
    (2,1,2,1),
    (3,1,3,1),
    (4,2,4,0),
    (5,2,1,1)
)

select MISC_ID
from HOLD

group by MISC_ID
having min(READY) <> 0;

 misc_id
---------
       1
(1 row)
```

---

Amended query to handle joining rules:

```
SELECT HOLD.*, RULE.*

FROM HOLD

INNER JOIN RULE
ON HOLD.RULE_ID = RULE.RULE_ID AND RULE.ENABLED = 0

WHERE MISC_ID IN (
    SELECT MISC_ID
    FROM HOLD

    GROUP BY MISC_ID
    HAVING MIN(READY) <> 0
);
```

Comment: This will return MISC_ID=2 too

Comment: No it will not, and it will be considerably faster than joining the table to itself (depending on indexes, of course).

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain "having min(READY) <> 0"?

Comment: @user1550668 This query groups all of the rows together by their `MISC_ID` value, and then it only shows the distinct `MISC_ID` values when the minimum value of `READY` across all of that group's rows is not equal to zero.  If your database engine supports satisfying queries completely by an index, then adding an index `(MISC_ID, READY)` will allow this query to run very quickly.

Comment: @user1550668 If you want to see what's going on beneath the hood, so to speak, run this: `SELECT MISC_ID, MIN(READY) FROM HOLD GROUP BY MISC_ID`.  All of the rows where the `MIN(READY)` result value is not zero contain the `MISC_ID` values returned by the query in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I forgot to specify one thing though and I have just made an edit. Another requirement is to link the RULEs that are ENABLED=0.

Comment: See the query I added to handle joining the rules to the results.

Answer (score 2):

Use `HAVING` and match the counts:

```
SELECT MISC_ID
FROM HOLD h
WHERE READY = 1
GROUP BY MISC_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HOLD h2 WHERE h2.MISC_ID = h.MISC_ID)
```

Or, use an anti-join on itself:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MISC_ID
FROM HOLD h
LEFT OUTER JOIN HOLD h2 ON h.MISC_ID = h2.MISC_ID AND h2.READY <> 1
WHERE h2.MISC_ID IS NULL
```

Or, use `HAVING` and compare the MIN and MAX values:

```
SELECT MISC_ID
FROM HOLD
GROUP BY MISC_ID
HAVING MIN(READY) = 1 AND MAX(READY) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
    Select * from TABLE_HOLD th

    group by MISC_ID

left join

(    Select MISC_ID from TABLE_HOLD

    group by MISC_ID having READY=0 ) temp_table on (th.MISC_ID=temp_table.MISC_ID)
where temp_table.HOLD_ID is null
```