# Return set(s) ID only if all items from that set meet a certain criteria

Tags: mysql

I have looked at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411885/sql-to-select-rows-only-if-all-of-them-meet-a-criteria), but I can't seem to wrap my head around how the answers work in order to apply them to my case.

I have sets of articles (set_table)

```
ID SET   ID ART
1        1
1        4
2        1
2        4
3        2
1        3
```

Those articles have a table with their parent ID. (article_table)

```
ID ART   ID PARENT
1        1
2        3
3        2
4        1
```

Then those parents have a condition they have to meet, but it could be multiple (parent_table):

```
PARENT ID  GROUP ID
1          6
2          15
3          12
```

Meaning, I have to select all sets whose articles (all of them) are in GROUP 6, then the result should be ID SET: 2. Or I could need to select all sets whose articles (all of them) are in GROUPS 6 and 15, then the result should be ID SET: 1. Or I could need to select all sets whose articles (all of them) are in GROUPS 6, 12; then the result should be NULL.

I have tried:

```
SELECT parent_id
FROM parent_table
WHERE group_id IN (6,15)
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT group_id) = 2; -- Number of group ids
```

Which is cool, but I don't manage to filter the sets correctly, my attempts in selecting the set are not working.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: is it not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: `but it could be multiple` Eh?

Comment: @Strawberry I meant that it could be a single condition (group_id = 6) or a multiple condition (group_id = 6 AND group_id = 15 AND ...), as explained below. Sorry, English is not my primary language.

Comment: But parent_id appears to be unique

Comment: Yes, @Strawberry, but you can have different articles with different parents in the same set, and I can't select the set unless all articles in the set belong, through their parents, to a certain group or groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below is not so painful once you start writing it.  Just join together the three tables, and then use conditional aggregation to count the number of entries in an `ID_SET` which have the desired groups.

The following query finds the `ID_SET` values which have groups of either 6 or 12.  Note that this will return an empty result set for the sample data you gave in your original question.  The `DISTINCT` subquery is needed to remove duplicates group values which would otherwise throw off the conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT t.ID_SET,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.GROUP_ID IN (6, 12) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS groupCount
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT s.ID_SET, p.GROUP_ID
    FROM set_table s
    INNER JOIN article_table a
        ON s.ID_ART = a.ID_ART
    INNER JOIN parent_table p
        ON a.ID_PARENT = p.PARENT_ID
) t
GROUP BY t.ID_SET
HAVING groupCount = 2   -- change 2 to however many group values you want to match
```

Comment: I have been trying this for a while with the actual tables, but the SELECT inside the INNER JOIN returns groupCount values double (or triple some times) of what they should... I am trying to figure out why (maybe it's the query, maybe is the data), but the query looks NICE!

Comment: @Ika I have updated my answer.  I tested it in MySQL console proper and it appears to be working.

Comment: This is perfect!! This last version works smoothly and it is simple enough to understand how it works. I have been programing less than a year and it is great to have your help. Hopefully I can do the next one by myself. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ika Glad I could help you out, look forward to seeing you again on Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
select ID ART 
from articles a 
join Parent1 p1 on a.ID ART = p1.ID ART 
join Parent2 p2 on p1.ID PARENT = p2.PARENT ID AND p2.GROUP ID in (6,12)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this wouldn't select the sets, and also it seems it would select articles in either groups 6 or 12, but not just the ones in both of them.